# Adding SSH key to ssh-agent

Tags: macos, ssh

I am learning Git and Github.
I am trying to push few changes onto the Github server.

I have generated the SSH key and also added the public key on Github. I am not however able to add it to the ssh-agent.

I tried following the instructions as mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent), but the terminal displays the following, i.e., there is no file or directory "`/.ssh/config`".

Even the command to create the file "`touch ~/.ssh/config`" does not seem to work.

Any ideas on how to complete this would be helpful.

[image]

**Edit 1**: This is where I am at in VS Code.
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241324/discussion-on-question-by-paras-khosla-adding-ssh-key-to-ssh-agent).

Answer (score 2):

The instruction you mention are:

- for a private key that was passphrase-protected
- for adding said private key, not `~/.ssh/config`: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` or `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

`~/.ssh/config` is only needed for non-conventional private key filenames/file path.

For instance:

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/path/to/my/private/ky
```

(the private key can be defined anywhere, with any name)

You would then use the URL `gh`: `ssh -Tv gh`

```
git ls-remote gh:me/myRepo
```